# Realtime log stream from cloudwatch to logstash

Tags: amazon-web-services, logstash, amazon-cloudwatch, filebeat, logstash-forwarder

I have been using [Cloudwatch Logstash plugin](https://github.com/lukewaite/logstash-input-cloudwatch-logs) to stream Lambda application logs from Cloudwatch to Logstash. But lately it is taking more thank 6 hours for some of the logs to be pulled into logstash. I have checked logstash logs and there are no errors, but I can see .sincedb file is lagging behind.
Elasticsearch support suggested that since that isn't an official plugin, so I should go with [AWS module for Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-aws.html) which is a module for aws logs. It uses filebeat s3 input to get log files from AWS S3 buckets with SQS notification.
The documentation is available at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-aws.html.

But according to AWS documentation about [exporting application logs from Cloudwatch into S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3Export.html)

> Log data can take up to 12 hours to become available for export

But I want to export data in real time. I have raised this in AWS support forums, but I am not getting any reply. Can someone please suggest a way to stream application logs from Cloudwatch into Logstash in real time

Answer (score 1):

One of options is too directly redirect lambda log into ES. If you use python,  you could use the [python lib](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.15.0/). With this approach you are pretty sure to have realtime dataflow, but without logstash component.

Comment: But if I do that I will have to duplicate the input filters and output formatting that I have setup in logstash. There are other sources of logs as well

Comment: Yes, you can use a dedicated index for this dataflow (and reput it in logstash to follow the main path of other logs but... this looks strange..)